# In meminfo, sometimes Mapped more than Cached

Tags: cache, meminfo

In `/proc/meminfo`, AFAIK

> Cached >= Mapped

But after `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, it goes to

> Cached < Mapped

```
Cached:            66132 kB
Mapped:            67792 kB
```

`/proc/meminfo` contents after:

```
MemTotal:         369020 kB
MemFree:           34588 kB
Buffers:             184 kB
Cached:            66132 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           246624 kB
Inactive:          29688 kB
Active(anon):     209728 kB
Inactive(anon):     9920 kB
Active(file):      36896 kB
Inactive(file):    19768 kB
Unevictable:          12 kB
Mlocked:              12 kB
HighTotal:             0 kB
HighFree:              0 kB
LowTotal:         369020 kB
LowFree:           34588 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        210040 kB
Mapped:            67792 kB
Shmem:              9644 kB
Slab:              27520 kB
SReclaimable:       7500 kB
SUnreclaim:        20020 kB
KernelStack:        3160 kB
PageTables:         5004 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      184508 kB
Committed_AS:    1832660 kB
VmallocTotal:     499712 kB
VmallocUsed:        2708 kB
VmallocChunk:     417128 kB
```

Anyone know this issue?

Comment: I am stuck with the same question. Did you find the reason?.